# Problem writing unit test case for export-to-csv in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a unit test case for [export-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv) library in Angular. I am getting the error `generateCsv` has never been called. I can see the whole code getting executed in the coverage file. Below is my code snippet.

Component code

```js
exportToCsv() {
const options = {
      quoteStrings: '"',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: false
      }
const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv(options);

const downloadData = [{obj1: 'abc'}, {obj2: 'xyz'}]
csvExporter.generateCsv(downloadData);
}
```

Spec code:

```js
it('test1', () => {
    const csvExporter = new ExportToCsv({});
    spyOn(csvExporter, 'generateCsv');

    component.exportToCsv();

    expect(csvExporter.generateCsv).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      {
        'obj1': 'abc', 
        'obj2': 'xyz'
      }
    ]);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your spy is registered to a specific instance of `ExportToCsv`, but `exportToCsv` creates a new instance of `ExportToCsv`, which doesn't have the spy registered. I've done some renaming of `csvExporter` in your original code for clarity.

```
// Component code
exportToCsv() {
const options = {
      quoteStrings: '"',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: false
      }
const csvExporter1 = new ExportToCsv(options);

const downloadData = [{obj1: 'abc'}, {obj2: 'xyz'}]
csvExporter1.generateCsv(downloadData);
}

// test code

it('test1', () => {
    const csvExporter2 = new ExportToCsv({});
    spyOn(csvExporter2, 'generateCsv');

    component.exportToCsv(); // <-- this uses csvExporter1, bypassing the spy on csvExporter2

    expect(csvExporter2.generateCsv).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      {
        'obj1': 'abc', 
        'obj2': 'xyz'
      }
    ]); 
    // ^^ this fails, because we haven't done anything with csvReporter2, just csvReporter1
  });
```

I'm not as familiar with Jasmine as Jest, but I'd guess that the spy should actually be registered to `ExportToCsv.prototype`, e.g.

```
it('test1', () => {
    spyOn(ExportToCsv.prototype, 'generateCsv');

    component.exportToCsv();

    expect(ExportToCsv.prototype.generateCsv).toHaveBeenCalledWith([
      {
        'obj1': 'abc', 
        'obj2': 'xyz'
      }
    ]);
  });
```

That way, when the new instance of `csvExporter` is created in `exportToCsv`, it comes with the spy function attached to the prototype.